# Django - Website Bootstrap Design Breaks For Production

Tags: django, macos

I'm following the Try Django Tutorial #37 on Youtube and around the 11 minute mark, after the author sets `DEBUG = False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` to put the website into production mode, he runs the server again and the website appears nicely designed on his end. However, when I run it again on my end while following along, the `Bootstrap` design of the website completely falls apart with some images not even showing up.

I'm suspecting that this has something to with the `static_in_env` vs. `static_in_pro` when it comes development vs. production, but I'm not sure, just a beginner. Also, the following is what I'm getting in my command terminal:

```
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 102
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 404 95
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/img/marketing1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 99
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/css/navbar-static-top.css HTTP/1.1" 404 106
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/img/mvp_landing_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 105
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 100
[16/Jul/2015 17:31:20]"GET /static/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js HTTP/1.1" 404 115
```

Any help or advice on how to fix this issue is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `STATIC_ROOT` set? Have you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: I have `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")`. Is this only called when it's in production? Because if it is then this is for sure messing me up.

Comment: I have all my .css and .js and .html stuff in my "static_in_pro" by the way.

Comment: I upvoted your comment because it made me look in that area to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have deleted my own answer because I thought I solved my problem, but I refreshed the page again at the problem turned out to persist.

Comment: Correction, I have edited my answer, and the problem is solved, although I do not like the solution one bit.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, others had the same problem I did for unexplained reasons. Apparently, 
`python manage.py runserver --insecure` solves the problem. It's not recommended to to this in production, but only in the tutorials is this safe. I hope this helps others who get stuck at this point in the tutorials.